# cSipSimple application error:- 'SL_ANDROID_STREAM_VOICE' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: linux, android-ndk, pjsip

i am trying to run cSipSimple application on linux. To build it i am using link http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild. First i have installed all the packages. Then ndk and sdk was already installed in my linux machine. So i just set following path in .bashrc

> "export ANDROID_NDK=/home/nishant/JAVA/android-ndk-r6m-linux/ export
>   ANDROID_SDK=/home/nishant/JAVA/android-sdk-linux_86/ export
>   PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"

Now when i am running command make, i am getting following error:-

> /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:
>   In function 'opensl_create_stream':
>   /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:532:
>   error: 'SL_ANDROID_STREAM_VOICE' undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>   /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:532:
>   error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:532:
>   error: for each function it appears in.)
>   /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:557:
>   error: 'SL_ANDROID_KEY_STREAM_TYPE' undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>   /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:654:
>   error: 'SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_GENERIC' undeclared (first use in
>   this function)
>   /home/nishant/CSipSimple/jni//pjsip/android_toolchain/pjmedia/../../sources/pjmedia//../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c:669:
>   error: 'SL_ANDROID_KEY_RECORDING_PRESET' undeclared (first use in this
>   function) make[1]: ***
>
> [/home/nishant/CSipSimple/obj/local/armeabi/objs/pj_opensl_dev/../../android_sources/pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiode

The macro "SL_ANDROID_STREAM_VOICE" and other macros, defined in file "OpenSLES_AndroidConfiguration.h" , which is located in ndk. I don't get it, i am giving ndk path, but still why it's not able to trace it.

Am i missing something to set the path for NDK?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trace in ndk source for version android-ndk-r8d, file platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/SLES/OpenSLES_AndroidConfiguration.h:

Line 20:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {

// some source code

}
#endif
```

I think, it is better to define like that:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// some source code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I move all define in  platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/SLES/OpenSLES_AndroidConfiguration.h to pjmedia/src//pjmedia-audiodev/opensl_dev.c and it works fine. But this is not good solution.